# NullPointerException that freezes the application

Tags: javafx

I have a large (20k lines) application written in Java and JavaFX. There is dockable pane which contains a line chart. The error listed below occured and I have no idea where to looK for. This error does not appear too often and I cannot relate it to any process so far.

I would be happy if someone gives me a clue, please.

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:386)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:355)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.shape.PathUtils.configShape(PathUtils.java:45)
        at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_configShape(Path.java:251)
        at javafx.scene.shape.Path.impl_updatePeer(Path.java:304)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_syncPeer(Node.java:503)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2290)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2289)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2419)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you modify a scene from a background thread?

Comment: Most probably yes but it is hard to identify where this happens. This error seldom appears.

Comment: You are probably modifying a list in a "for" loop. try to avoid that. If you really have to do that please use "Itereator". Check SO for examples.

Comment: Also the ConcurrentModificationException is probably thrown in the initialize method of your controller. so it Can not be initiated hence The NullPointerException.